# AppContextSwitchOverrides in App.config not working

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I would like to add the AppContextSwitchOverrides settings in my app.config file from c# class library project instead of adding it programmatically :

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions", false)
```

But the settings from app.config does not reflect in my application - Please advice.

```
<runtime>
  <AppContextSwitchOverrides 
      value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions=false" />    
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this in appSettings in your web.config:

```
    <appSettings>
        <add key="AppContext.SetSwitch:Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto" value="false" />
        <add key="AppContext.SetSwitch:Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
```